# Accumulating Two Tensor Core wmma::accumulator Fragments

Tags: c++, deep-learning, cuda, gpu, cuda-wmma

Let's say that I have two instances of `wmma::fragment<wmma::accumulator, 16, 16, 16, half> a, b;` (namely `a` and `b`). How would I go about conducting an element-wise addition of `a` and `b` and storing the result back into `a`?

Comment: The `wmma_extension` library could help: https://github.com/wmmae/wmma_extension

Comment: Of course you could also (in a lower level way) completely replace wmma with mma instructions.

Comment: You can access the fragment elements directly for element wise modifications

Comment: @Sebastian, the wmma_extension tip is super-helpful actually, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wmma fragments are actually stored in registers of the threads of a warp. So operations can be done, if each thread knows, what to do.

Scientists at the Tokyo Institute of Technology have developed a C++ library *wmma_extension* to (among other functions like recovering FP32 accuracy from TF32 tensor core operations) easily do arithmetic operations on wmma fragments.

The library can be found here: https://github.com/wmmae/wmma_extension

Doing arithmetic operations as a simple one-liner (plus the include) is shown here: https://github.com/wmmae/wmma_extension/blob/main/docs/ops.md

The scientists have released two related papers in 2023:

- https://arxiv.org/pdf/2308.15152.pdf (Reducing shared memory footprint to leverage high throughput on Tensor Cores and its flexible API extension library)
- https://arxiv.org/pdf/2203.03341.pdf (Recovering single precision accuracy from Tensor Cores while surpassing the FP32 theoretical peak performance)